# selenium IDE not removing attribute "readonly"

Tags: javascript, magento, selenium-ide

I've been using the Selenium IDE addon of firefox to build up a testing suite, and on one of the sites i've been working with there is a calender select for the date of order. There are times of the day that this won't exactly work as intended, so in order to allow this test to run i was going to set the script to remove the readme attribute of the text field for the calendar (as it doesn't let me type one otherwise) and carry on.

In firebug, this script broken into two parts works perfectly

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("datetime-picker")[0];
x.removeAttribute("readonly");
```

Yet, when i set two runScripts using the same lines, it doesn't want to work.

does anyone have any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each script is independent of the other, and will not keep any variables unless they are saved as a Selenium variable (currently JavaScript). You won't be able to save x in Selenium since Selenium won't know what kind of object that is, so just combine them:

```
<tr>
    <td>runScript</td>
    <td>document.getElementsByClassName("datetime-picker")[0];x.removeAttribute("readonly");</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```